# Windows Phone persistence options other than SQLite

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, persistence, storage

What are the alternative persistence mechanisms for persisting some lightweight data in a Windows Phone application being written in C#? (can a XML file be used?)

This application targets both WP7 and WP8.  Links to samples for the provided alternatives would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple options:

1. [Put an XML file in the local storage folder of your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx)
2. [If it is Key-Value pairs, use ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings to store it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)